# Cannot import nested custom exception class

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    public void someMethod() {} throws someException

    public class someException extends Exception { // Exception class
        public someException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }       
    }

}
```

Another class:

```
public class SomeOtherClass {

    public static void main (String[] args) {   

        SomeClass obj = new SomeClass();    

        try {
            obj.someMethod();
        } catch (someException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}
```

Eclipse complains that "someException cannot be resolved to a type". I tried to add

```
import SomeClass.someException
```

But then it says "The import SomeClass cannot be resolved"

You could of course put someException in a separate file, and not make it nested, is this the only way?

Comment: what if you just change the catch to `catch(SomeClass.someException e)`? And why is it `someException` not `SomeException` for your exception subclass?

Comment: Use it like ; catch (SomeClass.someException e)

Comment: Frankly, its probably a dumb idea to use a nested exception.

Comment: @user3573388, did my answer resolve your issue? If so please consider marking this as resolved.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the class by qualifying it with the class name, `SomeClass.someException`. If you'd rather import it, you have to put your code in a package. You can then do:

```
import yourpkg.SomeClass.someException;
```

---

Also, you got the syntax a bit wrong here:

```
public void someMethod() {} throws someException
```

it should be

```
public void someMethod() throws someException {}
```

(But perhaps that was a typo in your question.)

---

You may also want to consider making the nested class `static` unless you really need to reference the enclosing object:

```
public static class someException extends Exception {
    ...
}
```

Comment: @aioobe if we do not make the inner class static how can we make it the instance of the class?

Comment: Like this `someClassInstance.new someException()`.